# Notepad++ Regex for URL case to lower

Tags: regex, notepad++

Could someone tell me if it's possible to use a regex expression to convert a url to lowercase?

This is within a html img tag so we could find the urls by tag.

Here is an example of what i have

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/dir/dir/ImageName.jpg" />
```

And i need to lowercase the image name at the end.

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/dir/dir/imagename.jpg" />
```

The document contains furhter HTML so i cannot simply lowercase the entire document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following as a search term:

```
("http[^"]*")
```

and replace it with this:

```
\L\1
```

Comment: Top work sir, that works exactly as i needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: dont forget if replacing more that you follow the [to-lower with `\E`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html)! `\L\1\E` otherwise `\L\1" some OTHER text` OTHER will be `other`!

Answer (score 2):

This regular Expression should work to find the URL with capital letters:

```
(http.*[A-Z].*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})
```

**Note that you do need to check the "Match case" option**

Under "Replace with" use

```
\L\1
```

*How it works*:

The parentheses mean you are going to store the result found with what is between them.  In this case the whole thing is stored in `\1`

We then start by looking for `http` followed by anything (`.*`) until a capital letter `[A-Z]`.  Then more anything until a period followed by 2-4 letters (`\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`)

If you have further questions, leave a comment.

Comment: This seems to overrun and selects more than just the src tag. However, ctn's suggestion has worked spot on for my. Thank you for your time and input though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Un-check ". matches newline"

Answer (score 0):

For me, to convert upper case letters in links to lower case then :

> (http.*[A-Z].*.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})

worked as a regex in Text Crawler free (ver. 3.0.3) to find 2,238 links in a large file of mine, as does "http[s]?://.+?"

Though (courtesy of Stefan from Grepwin) the pattern of :

> ((http|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-]))

which includes the parenthesis - seems to find  more (3,2006)
and *href="http[s]?://.+?"* finds 3,0033 In Text Crawler I did not try the \L\1 to convert to lower case since that is an option offered in the program, and running the above says it  3,0033 were changed, though it only change the case (I hope!).

I had also found HTML Tags Change To Uppercase or Lowercase Software that converts uppercase letters in links to lower case, though it is $20 if you want to convert more than one at a time, and is very slow or can locks up with large files. But it seemed to work well to convert upper case letters in links to lower case in files that I used it for.

I do not know regex (imagine a world in which this was the written language!) but was looking to convert all the upper case caps in  links to lower case, and I searched a lot trying to find out how to do this.

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?