# How to lowercase selected text using a Replace RegEx in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to lowercase selected BACKTICKED text using a regex in Notepad++

Here's an example string:

```
Select * FROM `Weird_TEXT` WHERE
```

And the desired output:

```
Select * FROM `weird_text` WHERE
```

I can find these strings (including the backticks) using the regex:

```
(?<=FROM )(.*)(?= WHERE)
`Weird_TEXT`
```

But I can't figure out how to replace the text as lowercase, I've tried using the following:

```
\1\L\2\L
\1\L\2\L\3
```

EDIT:

When I click *Find Next* in Notepad++, the backticks around the word `Weird_TEXT` are included in the selection.  Could this be why the RegEx isn't working?

Comment: What do you get with your current attempt?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nothing happens

Comment: Also pertinent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073699/notepad-regex-for-url-case-to-lower/70246935#70246935

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put this in the replace box:

```
\L$1
```

Comment: Nothing happens, I wonder if is because the quotes ( ' ' ) are included in the search text?

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me, Npp v6.9.2 and `Regular Expression` checked.

Comment: There're no prblem with the quotes, `\L` doesn't act on them.

Comment: It's actually backticks, not quotes, I edited the question

Comment: @camdenl: It doesn't change anything, it works for me.

Comment: OK Weird it only worked when I clicked Replace All, thanks

Comment: @camdenl: I see. The replace acts only on selected string; `Replace all` is OK, you could also do `Find` to select the first then `Replace`, it will replace the selected and position on the next match.